# Decodificar os acentos na saida do subprocess shell

Tags: python

Estou executando o comando **dir** através do subprocess do Python porém ele me retorna a saída do comando sem os acentos.

**Código**

```
import subprocess

response = subprocess.check_output('dir', shell=True)
response = (str(response).replace('\\r','')).split('\\n')

for e in response:
    print(e)
```

**Saida**

```
b' O volume na unidade C n\xc6o tem nome.
 O N\xa3mero de S\x82rie do Volume \x82 8A39-7137

 Pasta de C:\\Users\\Loseys\\PycharmProjects\\Testes

02/01/2021  03:39    <DIR>          .
02/01/2021  03:39    <DIR>          ..
16/12/2020  11:44    <DIR>          .idea
25/12/2020  20:42             1.609 Backup_server.py
22/12/2020  11:16             4.777 C.py
25/12/2020  20:31             1.058 Chat.py
25/12/2020  20:14             1.504 Client.py
23/12/2020  09:39               234 client_port_80.py
18/12/2020  12:15             1.254 S.py
19/12/2020  01:54                 0 send.py
25/12/2020  14:53             1.408 server-positronx.py
24/12/2020  13:43               390 server_port_80.py
02/01/2021  03:39               171 simple.py
25/12/2020  21:24             2.290 temp.py
26/12/2020  13:12             3.032 X.py
26/12/2020  00:15               459 Y.py
              13 arquivo(s)         18.186 bytes
               3 pasta(s)   1.347.938.693.120 bytes dispon\xa1veis
'
```

**Decode**

Tentei decodificar a saída da variável response em latin-1 porém os acentos não saíram de forma correta, a saída permaneceu desta forma:

> O volume na unidade C nÆo tem nome.
> O N£mero de S‚rie do Volume ‚ 8A39-7137

Outra tentativa foi com o utf-8, no qual apresentou erro na decodificação do byte 0xc6:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position
> 24: invalid continuation byte

**Dúvida**

Como posso fazer com que os acentos da saíam de forma correta utilizando o subprocess?

Comment: Tenta pf: `response = subprocess.check_output('dir', shell=True).decode()`, acrescenta o `decode()` no final dessa linha

Comment: Não, ele me retorna as mesmas duas saídas de erro que eu apresentei acima...

Comment: Tenta com `decode(erros='ignore') ` e vê se satisfaz, mas de qualquer maneira o mais indicado para listar os ficheiros de um diretorio é https://stackoverflow.com/q/3207219/3162303